# How to load CascadeClassifiers in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a face recognizer software and I use following simple code to load opencv cascadeclassifiers. but it does not work! Can anyone explain why and how to solve it?

```
const char* faceCascadeFilename = "data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml";
const char* eyeCascadeFilename1 = "data/haarcascade_eye.xml";
const char* eyeCascadeFilename2 = "data/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
void initDetectors(CascadeClassifier& faceCascade, CascadeClassifier& eyeCascade1, CascadeClassifier& eyeCascade2)
{
    try {
        faceCascade.load(faceCascadeFilename);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    }
    if (faceCascade.empty())
        exit(1);
    try {
        eyeCascade1.load(eyeCascadeFilename1);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    }
    if (eyeCascade1.empty())
        exit(1);
    try {
        eyeCascade2.load(eyeCascadeFilename2);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    }
    if (eyeCascade2.empty())
        exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    CascadeClassifier eyeCascade1;
    CascadeClassifier eyeCascade2;
    initDetectors(faceCascade, eyeCascade1, eyeCascade2);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error: `Exception thrown at 0x0FC13DFA (opencv_objdetect2410d.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.`
 [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7yUd.jpg) ... [ExceptionError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HHdz.jpg)

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: @Miki , Sure. I've edited my question.